# Start a function in other c file with _beginthread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, visual-studio

I want to run a function in a thread in other c file that links to my file.but it encounters with an error!
ide: visual studio 2015
please help me.

some includes for power.cu file:

```
#include <process.h>
```

after, in the beginning of power.cu file:

```
extern "C"
void setup();
```

and the _beginthread function in power.cu file:

```
_beginthread(setup, 0, NULL);
```

and in the kmeans.c file:

```
void setup() {
int argc;
int argv;
    int     opt;
extern char   *optarg;
    char   *filename = 0;
    float  *buf;
    char    line[1024];
    int     isBinaryFile = 0;

    float   threshold = 0.001;      /* default value */
    int     max_nclusters=5;        /* default value */
    int     min_nclusters=5;        /* default value */
    int     best_nclusters = 0;
    int     nfeatures = 0;
    int     npoints = 0;
    float   len;

    float **features;
    float **cluster_centres=NULL;
    int     i, j, index;
    int     nloops = 1;             /* default value */

    int     isRMSE = 0;     
    float   rmse;

    int     isOutput = 0;
    //float cluster_timing, io_timing;      

    /* obtain command line arguments and change appropriate options */
    while ( (opt=getopt(argc,argv,"i:t:m:n:l:bro"))!= EOF) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'i': filename=optarg;
                  break;
        case 'b': isBinaryFile = 1;
                  break;            
        case 't': threshold=atof(optarg);
                  break;
        case 'm': max_nclusters = atoi(optarg);
                  break;
        case 'n': min_nclusters = atoi(optarg);
                  break;
        case 'r': isRMSE = 1;
                  break;
        case 'o': isOutput = 1;
                  break;
        case 'l': nloops = atoi(optarg);
                  break;
        case '?': usage(argv);
                  break;
        default: usage(argv);
                  break;
    }
}

if (filename == 0) usage(argv);
}
//in continues
```

and the error:

```
error : argument of type "void (*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "_beginthread_proc_type"
```

Comment: The full error message should contain more information. Information you should also be able to get [by reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex). What does it say about the thread-function? What does it say it returns and takes for arguments?

Comment: And if you're really programming C++, then use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead. Not that I see the point in creating a thread for that function. It just doesn't make any sense. It shouldn't even build.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  argument of type "void (*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "_beginthread_proc_type" KMeans power C:\Users\MajidSB\Desktop\Final\Power.cu 479

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex) for the correct type of a function used as a thread entry point.

Comment: Also, in your `setup()` function, you're using those `argc` and `argv` variables without initializing them, which will cause all sorts of interesting undefined behavior. And I didn't think Windows has `getopt()`? Are you using some compatibility library?

Comment: `_beginthread` requires a function of the form `void _cdecl setup(void*)`. You didn't provide that. You provided `void setup()`. The compiler is telling you as much. So... provide what is required and this problem will go away, letting you move on to the next. (and don't even *think* about casting as a way to hide this problem).